# How do I align images inside of a container that contains a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I have put the image inside of the paragraph tag itself and floated it right, however it moves it to the right but underlaps the container edge.

I have taken it out of the paragraph section as well and it still does the same. I have created containers as well for them. I want the image in the container with the paragraph. I have attached an image of the issue I am having as well as my css.

[image: Want to put this image in the paragraph]

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/keyboard.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: cursive;
}


/* GOOGLE FONTS*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cookie&family=Fuzzy+Bubbles&family=Jost:wght@700&display=swap');
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*ID Classes*/

#mainTitle {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #17e85f;
  text-decoration: underline solid;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

#container {
  border: 10px solid #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#footer {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*    REUSABLE CLASSES*/

.navbar {
  background-color: #0a861d;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar li a {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.search {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 75px;
}

.navbar input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding: 3px 17px;
  width: 129px;
}


/*SERVICES PAGE LIST*/

.servicelist ul {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

.servicelist li {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(60, 154, 118, 0.91), #15c723);
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.margin {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.scontainer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 50vmin;
  font-family: helvetica;
}


/* SINGLE CLASSES*/

a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #54b3d6;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #17e85f;
  text-decoration: underline solid;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

p {
  color: #b8dae2;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 10px 10px 24px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

.service_styling {
  color: #b8dae2;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 10px 10px 24px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

.imgcontainer {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: inline-end;
}

.realImgContainer {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: right;
}

img {
  /* max-width: 50%; */
  /* max-height: 50%; */
  /* border: 5px solid #FFF; */
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
  /* padding: auto; */
  /* width: 50%; */
}


/*
.imgHardware{
    float: right;
}


.imgSoftware{
    float: right;
}

.imgApp{
    float: right;
}

.imgCabling{
    float: right;
}
*/
```

```html
<!--  NAV BAR-->

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search this website">
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
<h1 id="mainTitle"> Services</h1>

<!--   MAIN SECTION-->

<section id="container">
  <h2> Things We Do </h2>
  <div class="servicelist margin">
    <h2>Hardware</h2>
    <div class="service_styling">
      <span>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                    <div><img class="realImgContainer" src="images/cpusocket.jpeg" alt="computer socket"></div>
                    </span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <h2>Software</h2>
    <p> We provide the latest software for all kinds of fields. We work directly with vendors to get the best rate - we provide competitive rates and offer affordable and simple subscription solutions - we also carry full version software that is subscription-free.
      <img class="imgSoftware" src="images/code.jpeg" alt="computer code"></p>
    <h2>Application development</h2>
    <p> We can create and deploy custom software for whatever task you need completed. Our seasoned developers specialize in C, C++ and Java. Allowing us to create versailte and flexible software. Our team will with work with you hand in hand to ensure you
      get exactly what you need. We will also provide 24/7 maintenance as well as upgrades on all of our in house software.
      <img class="imgApp" src="images/codedeveloper.jpeg" alt="someone coding"></p>
    <h2>Enterprise cabling</h2>
    <p> We have over 30 years of infrastructure cabling experience. We have in house techncians who can terminate and pull ethernet and fiber optic cabling. We use our own equipment and do all of our work in house - without the use of a third party. So we
      can give you a fair price as well as a clean and concise debriefing of the exact work we will be doing and its core benefits.
      <img class="imgCabling" src="images/switchandcable.jpeg" alt="switch and cable">
    </p>
    </ul>
</section>

<!--   SUB SECTION-->

<section>
</section>

<!--   FOOTER-->

<div id="footer">&copy; 2050</div>
```

Comment: Share the whole related code (both HTML and CSS) to the image for us.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated both stylesheet and html page shared.

Comment: You should replace the images with ones from [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/) to better demonstrate your issue. Of course we cannot see images with relative paths. Read the page on how to apply a certain image resolution.